# How to get all possible colors on desired spectrum?

Tags: color

I can imagine a very special red color in my mind but I can't find its color code in Photoshop or any other online color dictionary. Is there any tool that for example I say: "Hey show me all possible red colors exist in nature slowly so I can compare result with my taste to choose one"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: no

Long answer: "Red" is [very subjective](http://blog.xkcd.com/2010/05/03/color-survey-results/):

[image: Color Survey]

What you're thinking of "red" may be "orange" to someone else. Colors can also look vastly different when compared against two different colors.

Have you tried using the different color pickers in Photoshop? If you click the `a` radio button (and set a to 127) in the Photoshop Color picker, you can get a nice selection of reds:

[image: color picker]

Perhaps your issue isn't having a large enough gamut, but having *too* large of a gamut. Photoshop comes with quite a few built in color libraries, such a Pantone Solid Coated. If you click `Color Libraries`, you can flip through the available colors to look for some inspiration:

[image: PMSC]

Answer (score 1):

## [Try searching ColourLovers for red.](http://www.colourlovers.com/colors/search?hsv=0,359%7C0,99%7C0,99&sortCol=votes&sortBy=desc&publishedEndDate=01/24/2013&publishedBeginDate=12/16/2004&query=red&userName=&x=106&y=21)

Users have saved an insane amount of variations. You can even filter your results with HSB sliders!

[image]

## [Then head over to 0to255.com](http://0to255.com/ff0000)

Once you have your hex code, hand it over here. It's a nice visual way to browse through the value range of a given code.

[image]